How to stop server refresh event from logging event multiple times?
I am trying to learn Node.js. While combining events with server during self-practicing, I am facing a weird problem.
const {v4:uuid} = require('uuid');
const {format} = require('date-fns');
const Eventemit = require('events');      //Eventemit is a class
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');


const user = os.userInfo().username;

const eventemitter = new Eventemit();    //eventemitter is an object of the class Eventemit

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{

    const date_time = `${format(new Date, 'dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm:ss')}`
    eventemitter.on('log', ()=>{
        const req_string = `Log event: '${uuid()}' emitted by ${user} at time:    ${date_time} hrs.\n`;
    
        if(!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server_folder'))){
            fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'server_folder'), (err)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
        }
    
        fs.appendFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server_folder', 'server_log.txt'), req_string, 'utf-8');

        res.write(req_string);
        res.end();
    })
    eventemitter.emit('log');
})

server.listen(5000);

When I am refreshing localhost:5000 on browser, the log text file is registering it multiple times in one time instance (please refer to the attached screenshot).

Please help me with this issue, thanks in advance!

The issue you're facing is due to how event listeners work in Node.js. Specifically, you're adding a new listener every time the server handles a request, and since you're not removing the old listeners, each request accumulates more listeners, causing the log event to be handled multiple times. Does this clear things up?

Also design-wise you don't need events for this at all. You could extract the contents of log handler to separate function and reuse it through the app.

This is an expected behavior: you've created an HTTP server in your code using http.createServer(). The callback function you've passed to createServer is called every time the server receives a request.
When you refresh the browser, it sends a new HTTP request to your server, which triggers the callback function (and writes log info to the console).
You can avoid it by moving log writing it outside the request handler
